# Understanding the scope of child/parent instance variables

Tags: objective-c, ios7, parent-child, scope, instance-variables

I have a question regarding variable scope with subclasses.

I have something like the following:

`ParentClass.h`

```
@interface ParentClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *myIdentifier;

- (id)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

@end
```

`ParentClass.m`

```
@interface ParentClass() 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myIdentifier;
@end

@implementation ParentClass 

- (id)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    if (self = [super init]) {
       self.myIdentifier = identifier;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

`ChildClass.h`

```
@interface ChildClass : ParentClass

- (NSString *)showMeTheIdentifier;

@end
```

`ChildClass.m`

```
@implementation ChildClass

- (NSString *)showMeTheIdentifier {
    return self.myIdentifier;
}
```

Then I go to implement the class and I get no compiler warnings, but the result of the NSLog is `(null)`

`ViewController.m`

```
...
ChildClass *c = [[ChildClass alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"abc123"];
NSLog(@"What's my identifier? %@", [c showMeTheIdentifier]);
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you missing the `self = [super init]` stuff in your `ParentClass` initializer, or did you leave it out for brevity in the question?

Comment: move `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myIdentifier;` to .h

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"Just c: '%@'", c);` output?

Comment: sorry... yeah... have the `self = [super init]` part - just forgot it in the pseudo-code

Comment: Looks fine to me. It should work. What is it logging exactly?

Comment: @Anoop I don't want the identifier to be changed from the *outside*. That is why it is a `readonly`. The only way to change it should be from the `init` method.

Comment: @ShantiK is is logging `What's my identifier? (null)`

Comment: i have created a dummy proj with exactly whatever u have typed in here.. It works for me.. it logs  What's my identifier? abc123
Are you sure you are not missing anything?

Comment: I checked your code, its perfectly working in my system. Do a **clean+build** and check again.

Comment: @Wain it says `Just c: <ChildClass 0x146d1620>`

Comment: Remove the property in the private category and use this in the init.         _myIdentifier = identifier;

Comment: removed the `readonly` in the public, edited to the `init` to use `_myidentifier` and commented out the `@property...` declaration in the .m file. Still no luck... very strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you have `self == [super init]` instead of `self = [super init]` in your "pseudo code" (you're comparing `self` to `[super init]` instead of assigning it), everything looks fine. If you're are using `==` in your actual code, self is returning `nil`.  You may want to try logging the actual child class and see if the object exists after you instantiate it (or set a break point and check the debugger).  That'll tell you if the problem is in instantiation or elsewhere.

Most likely, there's some other detail in your actual code that's causing the problem.  It's possible that something you think isn't related is actually the problem.  I've done this before when posting questions.  I try to cut out the "cruft" and end up also cutting out the problem.  You may want to try posting your actual code.

Comment: you are right - I could kick myself. I had an `if-statment` that was preventing the equivalent statement to my pseudo `self.myIdentifier = identifier` :head:desk:

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the property declaration in the private category and do something like this:

You are not returning self in init. Hence it does not work.

```
- (id)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        _myIdentifier = identifier;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: like I commented - that's not the problem. Just forgot to type it in my pseudo-code